# Is the following a Property or an Attribute of a Div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to insert a number calculated by some JS code and edit the 
data-number-value="127842" to a new number.

How can I access and overwrite this number using JS.

Is this a Property or a Attribute?

This is the DOM code:

```
<div class="et_pb_number_counter et_pb_module et_pb_bg_layout_light downloadcount et_pb_number_counter_0" data-number-value="127842">
<div class="percent" style="color:#e2332d"><p><span class="percent-value"></span></p></div>
<h3>Downloads</h3>
</div>
```

This is my JS

```
jQuery( ".downloadcount" ).setAttribute('data-number-value', downloadCount);
```

I cannot get it to work

Comment: Any such *text* that appears in the HTML markup is an *HTML attribute*. It is only a *property* if/when/how exposed by the DOM.

Comment: Look at the [tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info), in particular see the section marked **When asking a JavaScript question, you should**, pay special attention to the section which says *use the Developer Tools for your browser*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setAttribute` is a [DOM Method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute), which you can't use directly on a jQuery object.

Either access the native JavaScript object to use the setAttribute function with:

```
jQuery( ".downloadcount" )[0].setAttribute('data-number-value', downloadCount);
```

Or use the [jQuery data function](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

```
jQuery( ".downloadcount" ).data('number-value', downloadCount);
```

Comment: jQuery really? this can be done with ES6 and just as little code

Comment: @vol7ron - What's the issue? The OP posted jQuery code and I provided a jQuery answer.

Comment: Not saying it's wrong, just saying we have to teach him better ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery( ".downloadcount" ).data('number-value', downloadCount);
```

OR:

```
jQuery( ".downloadcount" ).attr('data-number-value', downloadCount);
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/aeay6fqe/)

Comment: I used the .data code and it works great. Thank you!

Comment: @JamieCarter, Glad to hear that

Comment: @JamieCarter, you can make this question as answered by selecting the real answer solved your problem. Doing that, helps others to do not take more time on this question

Answer (score 0):

No jQuery is necessary.  You can use `dataset` to access your data-* attribute in the DOM.

```
document.querySelector('.downloadcount').dataset['number-value'] = downloadCount;
```